# How can increasing the max of SALT deductions from 10kUSD to 72.5kUSD cause an average tax cut of 145kUSD for the top 0.1% earners (>1MUSD) in the US?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, state-taxes, ultra-rich

I read [an article from Fox Business](https://www.foxbusiness.com/politics/democrat-tax-deduction-rich-americans-reconciliation-bill) ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20211110044617/https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2020/09/04/the-salt-tax-deduction-is-a-handout-to-the-rich-it-should-be-eliminated-not-expanded/), [mirror 2](https://archive.ph/dxahB)) about the  proposed change to the  [State and Local Tax (SALT) deductions](https://smartasset.com/taxes/trumps-plan-to-eliminate-the-state-and-local-tax-deduction-explained):

> - Under the latest proposal currently being considered by the House Rules Committee, **the [SALT] deduction cap would rise from $10,000 to $72,500** for five years (it would be retroactive to 2021). The measure would then extend the cap through 2031.
> - A separate analysis conducted by the Tax Policy Center shows that households earning at least seven figures a year would receive the majority of the benefits. About 25% of the benefits would go to the top 0.1% of U.S. households, which would receive an **average tax cut of $145,000**, while 57% would benefit the top 1%, which would see an average cut of $33,100.

How can the increase of the SALT deduction cap from 10kUSD to 72.5kUSD yield an average tax cut of $145,000 for households earning at least 1M USD a year?

---

When I do the maths, assuming an individual earning 2M USD via W2+cap gain+dividends in 2021 in the US state with the highest state taxes (viz., California), I get the following:

- [699,839 USD](https://smartasset.com/taxes/income-taxes#HTa9HIsaAo) of federal taxes without SALT, standard or any other type of taxable income deductions.
- [239,921 USD](https://smartasset.com/taxes/income-taxes#HTa9HIsaAo) of state taxes.

After deducting 72,500 USD of state taxes from the individual's 2M USD income, 2,000,000-72,500=1,927,500 USD, which will get [673,014 USD](https://smartasset.com/taxes/income-taxes#KR8H6EkWvf) of federal taxes. The SALT deductions gave them a tax cut of 699,839 USD - 673,014 USD = **26,825 USD**, which has nothing to do with the average tax cut of **145,000 USD** that the Fox Business article claims. What did I miss?

Comment: Is it possible they're calculating the total tax cut, summed over the 5 years?

Comment: @NPSF3000 good point but I don't think so, since 5*26,825 USD = 134,125 USD (~11kUSD less than 145kUSD), and the same article says "while 57% would benefit the top 1%, which would see an average cut of $33,100.", and 33 kUSD for 5 years sounds way too small for the top 1% (top 1% ~=500kUSD of earning per year in the US).

Comment: FYI: [TaxPolicyCenter.org: T21-0252 - Increase Limit on Deductible State and Local Taxes (SALT) to $72,500, by Expanded Cash Income Percentile, 2021](https://www.taxpolicycenter.org/model-estimates/state-and-local-tax-salt-deduction-november-2021/t21-0252-increase-limit-deductible)

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks, these numbers make more sense. Hard to double-check precisely though as it's for all states, and each state has their own tax rate. But the numbers look plausible to me, at least for the top 0.1%.

Comment: FOX is not known for looking sharp at the details. Whatever creates clicks is good to write…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 145kUSD tax cut assumes that the SALT deduction cap is removed, and not increased to 72.5kUSD as Fox News incorrectly wrote.

[Source](https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2020/09/04/the-salt-tax-deduction-is-a-handout-to-the-rich-it-should-be-eliminated-not-expanded/) ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20211114225027/https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2020/09/04/the-salt-tax-deduction-is-a-handout-to-the-rich-it-should-be-eliminated-not-expanded/),  ([mirror 2](https://archive.ph/qM4tW)):

> Who would benefit from **removing the cap on the SALT deduction**? The rich – especially the very rich. Almost all (96 percent) of the benefits of SALT cap repeal would go to the top quintile (giving an average tax cut of $2,640); 57 percent would benefit the top one percent (a cut of $33,100); and 25 percent would **benefit the top 0.1 percent (for an average tax cut of nearly $145,000)**. The remaining four percent of the benefit of removing the cap would go the middle class (i.e. middle 60 percent), for an average annual tax cut of a little less than $27.

Also worth noting, this is an average and not a median. The median is certainly much lower.